# Send JavaScript array to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to insert data from my `select` box `option`s into my database table. My database table fields are `id_country` and `country_name`.

The database field `id_country` is populated from the `select` `option` value and the `country_name` is from the corresponding `option` text.
the code is like this..

```
<select id="id_country" name="id_country">
  <option value="17" >USA</option>
  <option value="16" >Canada</option>
  <option value="7" >France</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data=new Array();
        $('#id_country').find('option').each(function() {
            var id=$(this).val();
            data[id]=$(this).text();

        });     

    $('#btn_insert').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(response){
                alert(response);
            }
        });                                     
    });

});
</script>
```

The server side script:

```
<?php
     //echo $_POST['data'];
    $arr=$_POST['data'];
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
       $sql="INSERT INTO Country($key,$value)";
       $query=mysql_query($sql);
       if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
          echo "success";
       }
     }
?>
```

I can't get `$_post['data']` value. How do I get the Javascript Array in the PHP script?

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions.  They're deprecated in all but name, old, insecure and are meant for interfacing with versions of mysql that have been obsolete for years now.  Consider switching to mysqli or PDO

Comment: Have you outputed $_POST yet as suggested by @MatthewBlancarte, this will let you know what you ACTUALLY have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below:

First serialize your array and then pass to jquery ajax function.

```
data.serializeArray();
```

In PHP Script, at the beginning of file,

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
```

Answer (score 1):

There must be an data-member inside the data-object when you want to fetch all sended data using `$_POST['data']`

Change this:

```
data:data,
```

into

```
data:{'data':data}
```

when you want to post only the data of the selected option, you must build the data-object inside the click-handler, like this:

```
var data={'id_country':$('option:selected','#id_country').val(),
          'country_name':$('option:selected','#id_country').text()};
```